# Can't add ruby code to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I add my rails code into my jquery I have this problem:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Here my controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @a = "12345"
    end
end
```

My index.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        var a = <%= @a %>
        var url = "http://www.google.com"
        console.log(a)
    }); 
});
```

I don't know how to fix that, please help me!

Comment: Your `index.js` file isn't rendered by `erb`. Put it in your views in `index.js.erb` instead and create appropriate action for it.

Comment: `var a = '<%= @a %>'` Use this. Wrap it in quotes

Comment: @ShaunakD it won't help.

Comment: when I change index.js to index.js.erb, I have new error :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: missing `;` in your js code. I suggest you read something about javascripts syntax

Comment: Sorry, still the same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the filename to `index.js.erb` so that rails understands that you want to insert ruby code inside your javascript.

Also fix your javascript code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        var a = "<%= @a %>";
        var url = "http://www.google.com";
        console.log(a);
    }); 
});
```